# How to change the url in codelginter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My url is http://mydomain.com/controllername/method/ .

Now I need the site url like.
http://mydomain.com/method.

mydomain name wants to access as a controller name .
for example. url like
www.testing.com/pages.  'testing' act as a controller in codeigniter.

Explain how to get the controller name from the domain name. and also how to remove the controller name(www.mydomain.com/controllername/method) from the url.

I need the url like www.controllername.com/method

Answer (score 2):

In application/config/routes.php use this code

```
$route['method'] = 'controllername/method';
```

for routing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Routes. [Routes in codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define routes in

application/config/routes.php.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

This may help.

Answer (score -2):

IMO this would best be done with your .htaccess file instead of CI routes. I am not the best with these rules, so typo may exist, this is the general idea:

```
// If HOST contains www, strip www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

// If URI contains DOMAIN.COM, it was probably just redirected, dont do it again!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^%{HTTP_HOST}
// Re-write http://domain.com/method to http://domain.com/domain.com/method
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I appreciate constructive criticism. Can someone please provide some feedback as to why my answer was downvoted. I see many other answers here that don't attempt to answer the OP's question, yet they have been upvoted. He wants to extract the domain name and use it as a controller...unconventional...so I am providing a method of doing this with a well known Apache mod instead of trying to re-invent the wheel that is called CodeIgniter. So...please, help us all out if you know better.