# I want to hide the controller names form the url

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, uri

I want to hide the controller names from ther url. I tried using the `routes.php` file in config folder.

the code in the file is like this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "controller_home_body";
$route['(:any)'] = "auth/$1";
$route['login'] = "controller_user_login";
$route['index'] = "controller_home_body";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

but the `url` is still like this

```
localhost/vivahaya/index.php/controller_user_login/user_login
```

how can i solve this thing? any idea?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302590/hide-codeigniter-controller-name-from-url-with-multiple-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16234098/1671234

and right action name as well in config route like

```
$route['login'] = "controller_name/controller_user_login";
```

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "controller_home_body";
$route['login'] = "controller_user_login/user_login";
$route['index'] = "controller_home_body/index";
$route['404_override'] = '';

i try this way but the url is showing whole thing

Comment: ok type yourdomain.com/login
and use ancor function of ci
 or use <a href="yourdomwin.com/login">click</a>
it will work

Comment: when some one click the loging button the form action is sending the request to controller_user_login/user_login method.
and if he is a valid user then i redirect him to the main index page 
using the 
redirect('controller_home_body/index');
inside the user_login method. 
is i'm doing a wrong thing here?

Comment: you can use redirect('index'); only

Comment: sir sorry for disturbing, need to know just a one thing
now the url is showing like this.
vivahaya/index.php/index 
can i remove the index.php part from the url?

Comment: i can tell u tomorrow i have to leave now its saturday

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value with your `controller name`

```
$route['login'] = "controller_name/controller_user_login";
$route['index'] = "controller_name/controller_home_body";
```

Comment: actually i'm new to codeigniter. so can you kindly tell me what is the controller_name means ? for the moment i have two files in my controller folder as controller_user_login.php and controller_home_body.php